# Mongoose auto increment ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I would like to create increment id with three formats
For students it will be with 5 column  starts from 00000
For teachers it will be 3 starts from 000 and so on ..
How do i do that
I tried auto-increment npm package but it seems that it's not supported anymore

Student model:

```
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const studentSchema = new Schema({
  studentId: {
    type: Number,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

Comment: Have you looked into [mongo-sequence](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence)?